# Aninhar Classes e tags CSS

Tags: css, html5

Estou desenvolvendo um site, lado Administrativo, já montei a MasterPage e agora definindo o Layout das páginas filhas, onde me deparei com um problema, o qual preciso de ajuda.
Este é o código que interessa na página filha:

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentFormAdmin" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="FormAdminBase" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <header id="HeaderFormAdmin">
                <h2>Cadastro dos Serviços Prestados</h2>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Então criei o `CSS` conforme segue:

```
#FormAdminBase {
    background-color: #285ce6;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 15px;
    height: calc(100% - 5px);
    border: 3px red ridge;
}

#FormAdminBase h2 {
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgba(31, 54, 99, 0.73);    
}
```

A coisa é que "Cadastro dos Serviços Prestados" fica alinhado a esquerda do navegador e não a esquerda, dentro do "**FormAdminBase**" como eu imaginava que ficaria.
Gostaria de saber como aninhar tudo em "**FormAdminBase**".

Estou utilizando ASPX, C#, com Bootstrap!

Já pesquisei sobre e não encontrei nada direcionado, pode até ser que não soube pesquisar, mas fica meu pedido de ajuda!

Comment: No caso ele fica posicionado fora do elemento pai? Tem como adicionar uma *print* de como fica?

Comment: Separei estes estilos e HTML para um html estático, e ele está dentro do elemento pai normalmente. Provavelmente algum pai do `#FormAdminBase` deve estar afetando o estilo do `<h2>`... tente ver, nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do Chrome ou do Firefox, qual o estilo "computado" do elemento.

Answer (score 1):

Grato pela ajuda Wtrmute!
Fiz conforme tua indicação e vi que o meu erro foi utilizar o `<header>`, então eliminei-o e coloquei uma `div`, daí funcionou como esperado.

Ficou assim:

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentFormAdmin" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="FormAdminBase" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="HeaderFormAdmin">
                <h2>Cadastro dos Serviços Prestados</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Bom, era isto, o `header` estava certo, porem pra ser utilizado na **MasterPage** e não nas que a herdam.

Seguindo a dica do Anderson, quero esclarecer que o `header` é tratado no CSS conforme segue:

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Assim, ao declarar o uso na filha, daria o erro reportado inicialmente.

Mais uma vez, meus agradecimentos! Sempre aprendendo!

Comment: Parece-me o mesmo código da pergunta. O que exatamente você mudou?

Comment: Antes eu tinha na sequência 2 `div`s e o `header`, agora tenho 3 `div`s...

Comment: Ah, agora foi corrigido, mas mesmo assim não faz sentido. Por padrão, o elemento `header` tem o mesmo comportamento do `div`, por quê funcionou em um e para outro não? Você possui algum estilo no CSS que é aplicado diretamente nos elementos `header`?

Comment: Então Anderson, depois de postar, enquanto você comentava eu estava alterando!
bom, sim, eu tenho um tratamento do header, conforme segue:

    header {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 60px;
    }

E foi utilizando-me da dica do Wtrmute que encontrei esta falha!

Comment: Agora faz todo sentido. Acredito que você deva incluir isso na resposta para deixar claro qual era o problema de fato.